# Is there a way to load a spreadsheet to jenkins?

Tags: selenium2, jenkins

I'm trying to write tests to load a spreadsheet that populates users to a program site.

I was wondering if I can have a spreadsheet loaded to the site when the test runs on Jenkins.

To be more specific, the application takes a spread sheet by browsing its location. What I want to do, is specify the location of the file in test environment, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an example project that uses Java and runs your tests on SauceLabs](http://djangofan.github.io/simple-selenium-builder-framework/).   This project is executed using Maven and so you can load it in Jenkins.  Also, there is an included example of driving a test from a spreadsheet.